# Android connectivity with sql database

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services

I'm new to android technology. Can anyone, please, suggest me some proven idea to connect an android application from my laptop to a remote sql database server (without using php). I got connected from my java file to the database. But the output is displayed in the console part. How to get it displayed on the android screen?

Comment: can u pls suggest me with some website to try with web services.. it will be much batter for me..

Comment: search on S.O. with [android]+webservice, you will get very good useful answers. you can also try google.

Answer (score 0):

For using webservies in Android you will require Ksoap Library.